# Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See "URL" to learn more

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, post-ban

My friend's account is locked to **Ask Question**. It is shown the error message when he clicks **Ask Question**.

Error message:
**Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/377968) to learn more.**

How to solve this problem?

Comment: "my friend", aham, sure.

Comment: Try actually reading the linked FAQ entry

Comment: @creinig: You mean http://goo.gl/C1Kwu ? Who whould think of that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you clicked the link?

Your friend has been question-banned because his questions were probably of low quality, got downvoted a lot and got closed.

One thing he can do is to edit his question in order to improve them and get the question get reoponed.